# Find the value of $a>1$ such that the curve $y=a^x$ meets the line $y=x$ once and only once.

Tags: calculus

Find the value of $a>1$ such that the curve $y=a^x$ meets the line $y=x$ once and only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derivative of $y=a^x=e^{x\ln a}$ is $e^{x\ln a}\ln a= y\ln a$ and shall equal the derivative $1$ of $y=x$ at a point where $y=x$. That is, at this point we have $a^x=x$ and $a^x\ln a=1$ at the same time, hence $x=\frac1{\ln a}$, which makes $x=y=e^{\frac{\ln a}{\ln a}}=e$ and finally necessarily $a=e^{\frac 1x}=e^{\frac1e}$.

Comment: how do you know the derivatives have to be equal?

Comment: the derivative is strictly increasing in case of $y=a^x$ and equal to 1 in case of y=x. IF at y=x the derivative is less than 1 then the functions would meet again.Drawing a graph of $y=x$ and $y=a^x$
should make it clear.

Comment: What about if $a\leq1$?

Comment: the derivative will always be -ve. so it would meet only at one 1 point.At x=0 -> y=1, from there on as x inc. ,y dec.Again drawing a graph makes it easier.

Comment: ya, I agree.  I think any $a$ between $0$ and $1$ satisfies the requirements in the original question.  However, it's more likely that the question was just transcribed incorrectly from a homework assignment, and the answer from Hagen is the only interesting one.